# Do a setcounter only for an included file

Tags: sectioning, counters

I have currently the following situation: I am including a Latex-File in my main file. This file already has several `\section{}`-parts. Now I want to let their counting begin at `1` again, but without messing up the global counting in my master file. I tried the following:

```
\subsection{First}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\input{first_file}
\subsection{Second}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\input{second_file}
```

That works for resetting the counter, but that also messes my global counting up. Is there a way to reset the counter without messing up the global document? I don't want to change the included files, and preferably I want to have a portable solution.
Edit: Explanation for messing up:
What I get is:

```
1
2
3
\begin{input}
1
2
\end{input}
3
4
5
```

What I want:

```
1
2
3
\begin{input}
1
2
\end{input}
4
5
6
```

Comment: How is it messing up your global document? Wrong hyperlinks?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Question edited, I hope that explains it

Comment: `\input` is no environment, so `\begin{input}...\end{input}` is effectively wrong

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I know, it was just an explanation. It should mark the beginning and the end of the included text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an auxiliary counter and use it for temporary storage of the section number.

Then use `\inputreset{file}` for inputting a file where you want to reset the equation number.

However, you'll have *big* problems as soon as you try loading `hyperref`.

```
\newcounter{storedsection}

\newcommand{\inputreset}[1]{%
  \setcounter{storedsection}{\value{section}}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \input{#1}%
  \setcounter{section}{\value{storedsection}}%
}
```

Comment: `hypertexnames=false` will generate unique names not based on counters, so the resetting of counter values should not have no effect on the links and bookmarks (at least for small MWE -- I could not test for any eventuality)

Answer (score 2):

This uses a temporary counter to store the section counter value before the first `\input` is used. In addition, the `\input` command is changed to `\refstepcounter` a input counter, which then resets the `section` counter in turn.

**Edit** Automated storing of the section counter value for first `\input`.

Some drawback: Each time if `\input` is used the section counter is reset. If this is a problem, one can remove the resetting after some threshold.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\newcounter{inputfilecounter}

\newcounter{storesection}


\xpretocmd{\input}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{inputfilecounter}}{0}{%
    \setcounter{storesection}{\value{section}}%
  }{}%
  \refstepcounter{inputfilecounter}
}{}{}

\newcommand{\RestoreSectionCounter}{%
  \setcounter{section}{\value{storesection}}%
}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{inputfilecounter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Regular}
\clearpage

\input{firstfile}
\clearpage

\input{secondfile}

\RestoreSectionCounter
\clearpage
\section{Continued regular sections}
\end{document}
```

[image]